# Toggle multiple Audio Play-Pause

Tags: javascript, css, html

My HTML, CSS and JS are all contained within their own files ('index.html', 'javascript.js', 'style.css').

I want to change the background-image of the button to represent its state.

Here are the current snippets I have:

```html
<button id="btn_playPause" type="button" onclick="losAudio_playPause()"></button>
```

```css
#btn_playPause {
  background-image: url(../contents/img/losAudio_play.png);
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
}
```

And finally, the JavaScript (point of failure)

```js
function losAudio_playPause() {
  var losAudio = document.getElementById("losAudio");
  if (losAudio.paused) {
    losAudio.play();
    document.getElementById("btn_playPause").style.background-image="url(../contents/img/losAudio_pause.png)";
  } else {
    losAudio.pause();
    document.getElementById("btn_playPause").style.background-image="url(../contents/img/losAudio_pause.png)";
  }
}
```

I am utterly lost as to why the `document.getElementByID("btn_playPause").style` parts aren't working, and can't find a solution.

Comment: `.style.backgroundImage`, not `style.background-image`.

Comment: In this case actually, you should toggle a class on that button and apply different background to different classes in css

Comment: Always, use developer tools and have an eye on **Console** for possible code (JS) errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Audio player with multiple tracks

Here's an example (with a really simple UI) that uses multiple tracks and [Play/Pause **Icons**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487069/383904) provided by [FontAwesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/).
Clicking on a track will pause all ongoing audio tracks and toggle play/pause for the clicked track.

- It reuses one single audio instance using `new Audio()`
- The actual audio tracks `src` are stored in every element's `data-audio` attribute:

```js
;/*SIMPLE AUDIO PLAYER*/(() => {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487069/383904
  const AUD = new Audio(),
      BTNS = document.querySelectorAll("[data-audio]");
  
  function playPause() {
    const src = this.dataset.audio;
    if (AUD.src != src) AUD.src = src;
    AUD[AUD.paused ? "play" : "pause"]();
    BTNS.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("pause"));
    this.classList.toggle("pause", !AUD.paused);
  }
  
  AUD.addEventListener("ended", playPause);
  BTNS.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", playPause));
})();
```

```css
[data-audio]{cursor:pointer;}
[data-audio].pause{color: #0ac;}
/*https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/*/
[data-audio]:before{content:"\f144";}
[data-audio].pause:before{content:"\f28b";}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<a class="fa"
   data-audio="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg">
   ACDC: Back in Black</a><br>
<a class="fa"
   data-audio="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/39/Metallica_-_Enter_Sandman.ogg">
   Metallica:Enter Sandman</a><br>
<a class="fa"
   data-audio="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/U2_One.ogg">
   U2: One</a><br>
```

---

(***Actual Answer:***)

1. Don't use inline JS, keep your JS logic in one place
2. Use `addEventListener` and the correct camelCase `style.backgroundImage` (or `style["background-image"]` if you will)
3. (Button is already a *"type=button"*)

```html
    <button id="btn_playPause">Toggle play pause</button>
```

```js
    var losAudio = document.getElementById("losAudio");
    
    function losAudio_playPause() {
        var isPaused = losAudio.paused;
        losAudio[isPaused ? "play" : "pause"]();
        this.style.backgroundImage="url('img/"+ (isPaused ? "icoPlay" : "icoPause") +".png')";
    }
    
    document.getElementById("btn_playPause").addEventListener("click", losAudio_playPause);
```

Don't request new images on click! Use a [**CSS Sprite Image**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS-Sprites) for your element:

[image]

and change it's **background-position** on click:

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("losAudio");
var btn_playPause = document.getElementById("btn_playPause");

function losAudio_playPause() {
  var isPaused = losAudio.paused;
  losAudio[isPaused ? "play" : "pause"]();
  this.style.backgroundPosition= "0 "+ (isPaused ? "-32px":"0px");
  // or use: audio.classList.toggle("pause", isPaused)
}

btn_playPause.addEventListener("click", losAudio_playPause);
```

```css
#btn_playPause{
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENFH5.png) no-repeat;
  border:none;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<audio id="losAudio" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg">Audio not supported</audio>
<button id="btn_playPause"></button>
```

Comment: I concur - except currently trying to implement... getting 'null' errors. 

Can't wait to be sufficiently decent at this... whenever that may be.

Comment: @Life Expanded my answer with a live example and a better approach.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this is amazing, except no matter how I seem to implement, i am getting an error in the last line of JS. Firebug: 

`TypeError: btn_playPause is null
btn_playPause.addEventListener("click", losAudio_playPause);`

Forgive me for my inexperience. I am trying as hard as I can on my end though!

Comment: @Life does you js load before HTML?

Comment: @user2181397 FIXED. I understand now. Thank you to everyone for bearing with me. I truly appreciate it!

Comment: can you pls try by putting this  script tag and its content at the end of body tag Like this
<body>
  <!-- Other HTML-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>

</body>
It should be just before closing body tag

Comment: The complete example with multiple tracks works well with an absolute url source but I tried with a relative source (from a local file) and it does not work.... Any help ?

Comment: @user2305415 it should work absolutely fine. Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I did not figure out what was wrong (with url source, it works perfectly but with my local relative file, it did not work, strangely). I found another alternative code at this question : "How do I make a single Javascript script for multiple play/pause buttons on a single webpage?".

Comment: @user2305415 You did not responded to *"Do you have any errors in the browser console"*. So, hard to tell. But glad you made it. PS, I have local files and it works perfectly fine with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
.playPause {
    background-image: url(../contents/img/losAudio_play.png);
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
}

.playPlay {
    background-image: url(../contents/img/losAudio_pause.png);
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
}
```

and if no other classes are involved,

```
document.getElementById("btn_playPause").className = "playPlay";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("btn_playPause").className = "playPause";
```

the icons might not be exactly right but I would just change class name instead of messing with the images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(...)` . Note `backgroundImage` not `background-image` which is  a css  property.

Also it is better to use class rather than inline CSS since inline CSS have highest precedence and it will trouble you if you want to change it
Below snippet can help you
HTML

```
<button id="btn_playPause" type="button" onclick="losAudio_playPause()">Click Me</button>

<button id="btn_playPause_add" type="button" onclick="losAudio_AddClass()">Add Class</button>
```

JS

```
function losAudio_playPause() {
    var losAudio = document.getElementById("losAudio");
    if (losAudio.paused) {
        losAudio.play();
        document.getElementById("btn_playPause").style.backgroundImage="url(../contents/img/losAudio_pause.png)";
    } else {
        losAudio.pause();
        document.getElementById("btn_playPause").style.backgroundImage="url(../contents/img/losAudio_pause.png)";
    }
}

function losAudio_AddClass() {    // With class
    document.getElementById("btn_playPause_add").classList.add('demoClass');
   }
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/pg7rLc48/)

NOTE: `classList.add()` is used when you want to have multiple class on an element.Simillarly you can you `classList.remove()` to remove a class from an element.

This is just demo you can change as required