# Can't get Javascript player to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help making this javascript player play on click.

I was following an example. I thought I had everything correct, but I can't get it to play. I know the path to the MP3 file is correct because when the site loads up, the file plays.  But, I need the file to play on click.

Here's the code:

```
<a id="mtoogle" style="cursor:pointer;">
<img src="../../../Custom/images/speaker.png"></a>
<audio id="playTune">
<source src="../../../media/temp_Audio1.mp3">
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mtoogle').toggle(
function () {
document.getElementById('playTune').pause();
},
function () {
document.getElementById('playTune').play();
}
);
</script>
```

Can someone point out what I am missing? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: .toggle() just hides and shows the element it is applied on. Secondly .toggle does not take 2 functions like this as parameters.  http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: `style="cursorointer;"` you're missing a `:p` :D

Comment: Roko, you're saying I should have : behind "cursorointer" instead of ;?

Comment: I just went back and looked at the code.   I put it down wrong on here.  I'll correct the code in the original post.

Comment: William read: `cursorointer` != `cursor:pointer;` so yeah you're missing a `:p`

Comment: Thanks, Roko, I fixed that.  Is there anything else you see that is in error?

Comment: @WilliamHodge yes, and provided a solution

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.toggle()` does **hide/show**,  not what you need.

**First, check if is `paused`, than do `play()` or `pause()` respectively**

```
// Toggle audio play() / pause() methods
AUDIO[AUDIO.paused ? "play" : "pause"]();
```

where `AUDIO` is your HTMLMediaElement

Example:

```js
var AUDIO = $("#audio")[0];

$("#btn").click(function() {
  AUDIO[AUDIO.paused ? "play" : "pause"]();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="btn" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/qseZe.png"></a>

<audio id="audio">
  <source src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg">
</audio>
```

P.S: I renamed your ID's to something more meaningful for demo purposes

**[toggle-audio-play-pause-image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487069/383904)** here you can find another simple yet nice implementation for multiple tracks.

MOZ<sup>docs</sup>: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/paused

Comment: It still didn't work @roko-c-buljan.  Is there a way I can have you look at the entire document to see if there's any other issues?  It's a small webpage.  Not a lot of code.

Comment: Roko, I got it working now.  Your solution worked.  Thank you.

Comment: @WilliamHodge you're welcome! Glad you made it work. Hope it was just a minor issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is about `Toggle()` method .

It's also will work.

```
$('#mtoogle').click(function () { 
var tune = document.getElementById("playTune");
if(tune.paused)
  tune.play();
else
  tune.pause();
});
```