# Toggle multiple play/pause buttons using Howler.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, howler.js

I searched SE for a bit and I saw similar questions but nothing quite like what I needed help with.

I'm using Howler.js to stream audio on my site. The issue I ran into is that there are many songs on each page so when one song is playing, clicking the next song does not toggle the buttons...the music does start playing but the first song doesn't. I am aware that this is because I am using an ID such as `Id="bodyPlayBtn"` but I need it to toggle the buttons from the js currently. I thought of using `this.toggleClass(ion-ios-play ion-ios-pause)` in the `function clickSongPlay()` but that didn't quite seem to work. What is the best way to approach this?

Here is the relevant code:

**HTML:**

```
<div><i class="icon ion-ios-play" id="bodyPlayBtn" onclick="clickSongPlay('@song.Artist','@song.Title','@song.URL','@song.Album.ImageURL');"></i><i class="icon ion-ios-pause" id="bodyPauseBtn"></i></div>
```

If you are visual like me, this is what that div controls (blue arrow)

[image]

player.js

```
// Show the pause button.
if (sound.state() === 'loaded') {
    bodyPlayBtn.style.display = 'none';
    bodyPauseBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
} else {
    loading.style.display = 'block';
    bodyPlayBtn.style.display = 'none';
    bodyPauseBtn.style.display = 'none';
}

// Show the play button.
bodyPlayBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
bodyPauseBtn.style.display = 'none';

// Bind our player controls.
bodyPlayBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    player.play();
});
function clickSongPlay(artist, title, url, imageURL) {
    //debugger;
    player.playlist.push(
        {
            title: title,
            artist: artist,
            file: url,
            imageURL: imageURL,
            howl: null
        }
    );
    player.skipTo(player.playlist.length - 1);
    player.play();
}
bodyPauseBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    player.pause();
});
```

This code works really well with just one play button, but when two enter the picture is when things get messy!

Comment: This may be relevant to what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487069/383904